# Start loop from certain number to n number in python

Tags: python, for-loop

How to start a loop from certain number to n numbers in python.

Example: starting loop from 2 but ending based on n numbers
If I start a loop from 2 but wish to go through next 5 numbers how to achieve that?

2
3
4
5
6
7

Comment: `for i in range(start, start+length+1)`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function

Comment: @not_speshal, you don't need to add 1 to start+length.

Comment: @MarkLavin - Yes you do. `list(range(2, 2+5))` is `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. OP wants the **next** 5 numbers.

Comment: setting 'length' to 6 would make more sense though, since that's the desired length.. or calling it something else!

Comment: @JeffUK: "go through next 5 numbers" implies length (or whatever variable) is presumably 5. Hence the +1. Name of the variable can be whatever OP wants, it's irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: Sensible variable naming is important!

Comment: It is working for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Range will do that for you

```
start = 2
length = 6

for i in range(start, start + length):
    print(i)
```

Or you could leave range alone and add your offset onto the number inside the loop

```
for i in range(0, length):
    print(i+start)
```

Which would be less common but depending on the scenario this might be more readable.